# How do I sample audio from microphone in javascript, for microphone animation?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, mediastream

I am recording audio from microphone in a browser using MediaStream Recording API. I would like to provide user with a visual feedback of a pulsating microphone icon. Something like this, only tied to the actual sound amplitude from the mike. https://codepen.io/megwayne/pen/bWOYEj  How do I do this?

I am recording audio like this:

```
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    const audioChunks = [];

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });
```

Comment: you only have to toggle the `animation` CSS property from `pulse 3s` to `none`, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, but my question is about MediaStreamRecording API.

Comment: However, since you mentioned it, perhaps you could help me with this. How do I modify the CSS to make this mike about 5 times smaller and fit it in a toolbar? Pressing it would toggle recording on and off.